# Symfony 2.8 Upgrading Packages Problem For PHP 7.0

Tags: php, symfony

Yesterday I updated my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.0 in a docker project using Symfony v2.8.51 where I'm now facing the issue of some of the dependencies not working.

I upgraded my packages but I am getting an error for the doctrine bundle package.

When I load the project in my browser I am getting:

```
Unable to load class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry"
in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 309
at ClassCollectionLoader::getOrderedClasses(array('Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry', 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer', ...
```

the function this error is referring to looks like this:

```
    {
        $classes = array();

        foreach ($class->getInterfaces() as $interface) {
            $classes = array_merge($classes, self::getInterfaces($interface));
        }

        if ($class->isUserDefined() && $class->isInterface() && !isset(self::$seen[$class->getName()])) {
            self::$seen[$class->getName()] = true;

            $classes[] = $class;
        }

        return $classes;
    }
```

My composer json requirements look like this:

```
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "^2.6.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5.0",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "@stable",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "@stable",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "@stable",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "~2.0",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "symfony/console": "^2.5.6",
        "imagine/imagine": "@stable",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "@stable", 
        "soundasleep/html2text": "^0.5.0",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "1.1.10",
        "predis/predis": "^1.0",
        "stackify/monolog": "~1.0",
        "lexik/maintenance-bundle": "^2.1"
    },
```

I’m not sure what exactly I need to do to get it to work again or what would be the best approach to upgrade all of my dependencies correctly since I don't have a lot of experience with it.